# how to have fixed atom number in MATLAB wmpdictionary function?

Tags: matlab, dictionary

I'm trying to implement idea in MATLAB using wmpdictionary function. I need to construct a dictionary with N rows and M columns and then increase rows to N+a while having M (number of atoms) fixed.

Is there any way to construct dictionaries with arbitrary atom length (N) and fixed number of columns (atom number)?

Answer (score 0):

I found this way useful to solve this problem. first I create the dictionary with longest atoms, then I downsample it to get the smaller dictionary so that both are from the same origin.